# Access Default Value Giving #Size! Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, default-value

I am using an Access 2013 form for calculations.  I have a user inputting the hours they work in a text box for each day of the week.  Labeled accordingly txtMonday, txtTuesday etc.  I have a text box for all the hours worked txtTotalHours which I am setting the default value for with this formula `=NZ(txtMonday,0)+NZ(txtTuesday,0)+NZ(txtWednesday,0)+NZ(txtThursday,0)+NZ(txtFriday,0)+NZ(txtSaturday,0)+NZ(txtSunday,0)` this presents an error of `#Size!`

I thought the `NZ()` would account for any issues, but I still get an error.  What can I do to overcome this error and have my calculation show a 0 if all the days are zero or null or blank, OR the SUM if the days have a value input?

Comment: is the txtTotalHours control bound to a field? How about the txt<DayOfWeek> controls?

Comment: What happens if you remove that formula from the Default Value property and add it to the Control Source property of `txtTotalHours`?

Comment: @HansUp - good thought - I think that was the main problem - but the second issue (#Size) was coming because it was just concatenating all the days together as strings - then turning to a number - a really big number. I was getting "1+2+3" = "123" instead of 6

Comment: I didn't see that in my test, @dbmitch.  I had "General Number" in the Format property of the Format tab for those 7 weekday text boxes.  Then with Pinky's original formula as Control Source for `txtTotalHours`, the other text boxes were added as numbers without the need to apply `Val()`.  After I saw your response, I blanked out that Format property and saw the values concatenated as you described.

Comment: Would probably never happen if the fields were added from a table - or formatted properly from the start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do two things

First wrap each NZ calc in a Val() function - in case it's actually concatenating the text box values as strings - before you trying to convert to an integer value - assuming you have the TotalHours field defined as integer - you didn't say.

Second put the formula in the `ControlSource` property (not `DefaultValue`)  and then if you actually want it bound to a field, use code to update the actual field AfterUpdate

`=Val(NZ(txtMonday,0))+Val(NZ(txtTuesday,0))+Val(NZ(txtWednesday,0))+Val(NZ(txtThursday,0))+Val(NZ(txtFriday,0))+Val(NZ(txtSaturday,0))+Val(NZ(txtSunday,0))`